# Flash Programming(Adobe Air) Vs Objective C?

Tags: iphone, ios, flash, air

This isnt a Programming quest but i couldn't think of a better place to ask this question..

I recently started Developing Apps for **iPhone using Objective C and Apple xcode environment**.now i am quite comfortable with Objective c and iPhone SDK. But now my Company has decided to stop using XCode Environment to build apps but use **Adobe Air(Flash Programming)** to build apps instead and i have been asked to  start Studying Flash Programming and using Adobe Air.. since i couldn't find much information regarding developers or apps build with Adobe Air anywhere i had few questions in mind which i thought someone might be able to answer here

1. Yes **Flash will have the best animations** i guess but **isnt iPhone's Core Animation Framework ,use of Open GL or use of Game Engine's like Cocos2d available for iPhone good enouf** if compared with Adobe Flash??
2. **The Utility Apps can be better build with Apple's own Development Environment** even if entertainment apps that dont require much development task might be a bit easy with Flash
3. Apple Development Environment Xcode and iPhone Sdk must have **tons of better api's and features** then adobe air could offer??
4. I have no idea how actually Flash Programming is done.. so after getting comfortable with Objective C **is it really worthwhile to just let it go and start studying Flash**??

IT would be really great if someone can help me with which will be the right process to develop apps for iPhone Objective C or Adobe Flash ??

Comment: What was their reason for moving to Adobe Air? In my opinion, the only valid reason is multiplatform development. Otherwise, you will waste (not really waste, but it will take time) getting used to the new environment and you will not have access to all of the iPhone hardware features.

Comment: yeah so instead of switching to Adobe Air i switched to another Company :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage of flash, as sosborn said, is that you will be able to easily port the project to Android, iPhone, and other platforms. You guessed correctly when you said that apple's environment will be able to function with less issues. By going from flash to iphone, you may have some conversion issues to fix.

If the company wants to develop for multiple platforms, then that change is totally valid and smart. If the only reason is ease of development from a graphics standpoint, ask them to look into cocos2d. If they really must use flash graphics, they can be pretty easily set up for use with coco.

Comment: yes i made these points count during my presentation but i ended up changing my company in the end.. thnx anyway :)